# how to refresh a list of items based on the choice of the user (picker )

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

hello i'm new to xamarin forms and i did some searching but didn't find much.
i have a list of Items displayed on a page and i would like to refresh that list when the user choose from the picker.
 for example when the user chose monthly from the picker the list must be refreshed and show the items for this month i already have 3 functions functionDaily, functionMonthly, functionYearly that return ObservableCollection  but i don't know how to refresh the list when the user choose from the picker if somebody can help me Thanks

Comment: to refresh a ListView with different data, just re-assign it's ItemSource property

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do it:

#### Using code behind

The pickers have an event called `SelectedIndexChanged`, that tell you when you change an element of your picker, when it raises you can update the source of your list, for example:

```
picker.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
    if (!picker.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {
        if(picker[picker.SelectedIndex] == "By Day")
          myList.ItemSource= functionDaily();   
        else if(picker[picker.SelectedIndex] == "By Month")
          myList.ItemSource= functionMonthly();     
       else if(picker[picker.SelectedIndex] == "By Year")
          myList.ItemSource= functionYearly();             

    }
};
```

#### Using the ViewModel

Is almost the same, just instead of using the `SelectedIndexChanged` method, you can use the property `SelectedItem`, create a property and binding to it, and when the property change update your ItemSource (Your ItemSource should be binding to a List on the ViewModel).

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer thank you guys if somebody is facing the same problem here is the solution

```
    void Handle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        picker = sender as Picker;
        if(picker.SelectedItem.Equals("Monthly")){
            ListActions.ItemsSource = am.GetMonthlyActionsByUserAndDate(CurrentUser.GetUser, DateTime.Now);

        }
        if(picker.SelectedItem.Equals("Yearly")){
            ListActions.ItemsSource = am.GetYearlyActionsByUserAndDate(CurrentUser.GetUser, DateTime.Now);
        }
        if (picker.SelectedItem.Equals("Daily"))
        {
            ListActions.ItemsSource = am.GetDailyActionsByUserAndDate(CurrentUser.GetUser, DateTime.Now);
        }



    }
```